# Confusing translation for Euler

Tags: sentence-translation, mathematics, neo-latin

In this sentence from Euler's [*De Serie Lambertina*](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/532/), I'm having trouble deciphering the meaning (§ 20, p. 40):

> At vero quomodo vicissim series Lambertina ad aequationem trinomialem perduci queat, quaestio multo magis ardua videtur; unde operae pretium erit talem analysin exposuisse, quod opus quo facilius succedat, sequens problem praemittam.

The translation I have, as a start, is as follows:

> But again in whatever way the Lambert series is able to be followed to the trinomial equation, a far more difficult problem is found; from those efforts it will be valuable to have set forth such an analysis, because the work by which it follows more easily, I may set out in advance the following problem.

This doesn't really work and I've gone through it very carefully but I'm stuck. For example, the use of *perduco*, which might more accurately mean *leads through*, I've interpreted as *is followed*, because saying it *is able to be led to*  the trinomial equation doesn't make much sense. Then there's the second half, and I've experimented with it a lot, but I'm sure it's still off base. It seems like there's an important connection between clauses I'm missing, which makes me wonder if *quod* is a pronoun instead, but I didn't think that worked.

How could this be better translated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that *queat* is subjunctive: This is an indirect question, and the governing clause is *quaestio multo magis ardua videtur*. The context is that Euler previously talked about deriving the Lambert series from the trinomial equation, now – *vicissim* means “on the other hand, then again, etc.” – he turns to the return journey. I'm not entirely sure how to express *perducere* in English either; my understanding is that he wants to derive the equation from the series. Let's say:

> But how, on the other hand, the Lambert series may be developed into the trinomial equation, seems to be a much more difficult question.

*Operae pretium est* + infinitive is a standing expression meaning “it is worth it, it is worth the effort.” *Quod* is indeed a pronoun here modifying *opus*, “which work.” This is a relative continuation. (1) *Quo [hoc opus] facilius succedat* – “so that [that work] may succeed the more easily.”

> Hence it will be worth the effort to have set forth such an analysis; and in order so that that work will succeed more easily, I would first set out the following problem.

“First set out” is somewhat free for *praemittere*, you cannot really say “send ahead” in English here (in German you could!).

(1) A relative continuation is that thing in Latin where you don't say: *Id cum videret Caesar etc.* but rather: *Quod cum videret Caesar etc.* Romans loved them.

Comment: I had a feeling an indirect question might be involved here, thanks so much for the helpful answer!

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: In "quaestio multo magis ardua videtur", "multo (adjective) magis (adverb)" = "much more(ly)". Is "multo" dative or ablative?  Would the double-adverb, "multum magis" = "much(ly) more(ly)" be equally correct?

Comment: @tony *Multo* is also an adverb, and with comparatives (like here) identical to *multum*, which would be equally correct. I would guess it was originally the neuter ablative of the substantivized adjective *multus* (cf. English "by a lot"), but I don't know if that's true.